# NestJS unable to resolve dependencies inside module

Tags: typescript, nestjs, ioc-container

I have two modules: `AuthModule` and `UserModule`;

Here is what the `UserModule` looks like:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        forwardRef(() => AuthModule),
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
            UserRepository,
            UserAuthRepository,
            UserSocialRepository,
        ])
    ],
    controllers: [UserController],
    exports: [UserAuthService, UserSocialService, UserService],
    providers: [UserAuthService, UserSocialService, UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

This module has 3 services: `UserAuthService`, `UserSocialService` and `UserService`.

**Contents of the** `UserAuthService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserAuthService {

    /**
     * UserAuthService constructor
     * @param { UserAuthRepository } _userAuthRepository
     * @param { UserRepository } _userRepository
     * @param { UserService } _userService
     * @param { UserSocialService } _userSocialService
     */
    constructor(
        private readonly _userAuthRepository: UserAuthRepository,
        private readonly _userRepository: UserRepository,
        private readonly _userService: UserService,
        private readonly _userSocialService: UserSocialService
    ) {}
}
```

**Contents of the** `UserSocialService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserSocialService {

    /**
     * UserSocialService constructor
     * @param { UserSocialRepository } _userSocialRepository
     */
    constructor(
        private readonly _userSocialRepository: UserSocialRepository,
    ) {}
}
```

**Contents of the** `UserService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    /**
     * UserService constructor
     * @param { UserRepository } _userRepository
     * @param { UserAuthService } _userAuthService
     * @param { UserSocialService } _userSocialService
     */
    constructor(
        private readonly _userRepository: UserRepository,
        private readonly _userAuthService: UserAuthService,
        private readonly _userSocialService: UserSocialService
    ) {}
}
```

Both `AuthModule` and `UserModule` have the `forwardRef(() => Module)` import as they both depend on eachother.

However, the problem is inside the `UserModule`, more specifically `UserService`, for some reason it is unable to resolve the `UserAuthService` dependency producing the following error:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (UserRepository, ?, UserSocialService). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [1] is available in the UserModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If dependency is a provider, is it part of the current UserModule?
- If dependency is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UserModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing dependency */ ]
  })
```

And here is the structure of the `UserModule`:

```
user/
    controllers/
    dtos/
    exceptions/
    models/
    repositories/
    services/
        - index.ts
        - user.auth.service.ts
        - user.service.ts
        - user.social.service.ts
    subscribers/
    -index.ts
```

So even though all 3 services are inside one module and they are exported and marker as providers, NestJS is unable to resolve them for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

You have a circular dependency between your `UserService` and your `UserAuthService`. Both of these services should make use of `@Inject(forwardRef(() => OtherService))` to make sure the injection can happen even through the circular dependency.

Generally you should try to avoid these classes from depending on each other if possible, whether that means breaking up the scope of the class and having it only access exactly what's necessary, or merging the classes together it's hard to say.

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserRepository)
    private readonly _userRepo: UserRepository,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => UserAuthService))
    private readonly _userAuthService: UserAuthService,
    private readonly _userSocialService: UserSocialService
  ) {}
}
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserAuthService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserAuthRepository)
    private readonly _userAuthRepository: UserAuthRepository,
    @InjectRepository(UserRepoitory)
    private readonly _userRepository: UserRepository,
    @Inject(forwardref(() => UserSerivce))
    private readonly _userService: UserService,
    private readonly _userSocialService: UserSocialService
  ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure but I think you need to inject the repositories using `@InjectRepository`, as they do in this [example](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#repository-pattern):

```
@Injectable()
export class UserAuthService {

    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(UserAuthRepository)
        private readonly _userAuthRepository: UserAuthRepository,
        @InjectRepository(UserRepository)
        private readonly _userRepository: UserRepository,
        private readonly _userService: UserService,
        private readonly _userSocialService: UserSocialService
    ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Importar el modulo del servicio o entidad en el modulo actual

```
@Module({
  imports: [forwardRef(() => YOUR_MODULE)],
})
export class CommonModule {}
```

*NOTA: Debe exportar el servicio o entidad de YOURMODULE.TS par aque no salga error

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions